# Python - For loop through dictionary with value as findall regular expression

Tags: python, regex, csv, dictionary, for-loop

I have a csv file with information on weather everyday, by year. I've created a dictionary where the keys are the year and the value is a regular expression to collect all dates within a year, like so

```
import csv, re

with open('weather_data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

csvfile = csvfile.read()

years = {'year_92': re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/1992', csvfile), 'year_93': re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/1993', csvfile),
     'year_94': re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/1994', csvfile), 'year_95': re.findall(r'\d+/\d+/1995', csvfile)}
```

The CSVs first column is the date in mm/dd/yyyy format and the second is temperatures. What I'd like to do is use the best method to take all the temperatures in a single year and find their average.

Currently, I am trying to loop through the dictionary to append (ie.) every temperature in 1992, to a list so I could then average that list.

```
temps = csvfile[1]
temp_92 = []
 for line in years.items(), temps:
     temp_92.append(line)
     print(temp_92)
```

However, obviously something is wrong with this. The code does run, except it's giving back mm/dd/yy. I tried switching up the csvfile[] but no results.

Here is what my output looks like

```
[dict_items([('year_95', ['1/1/1995', '1/2/1995', '1/3/1995', '1/4/1995', '1/5/1995', '1/6/1995', '1/7/1995', '1/8/1995', '1/9/1995', '1/10/1995', '1/11/1995', '1/12/1995', '1/13/1995', '1/14/1995', '1/15/1995', '1/16/1995', '1/17/1995', '1/18/1995', '1/19/1995', '1/20/1995', '1/21/1995', '1/22/1995', '1/23/1995', '1/24/1995', '1/25/1995', '1/26/1995', '1/27/1995', '1/28/1995', '1/30/1995', '1/31/1995' ...and so on
```

EDIT: Here is some example data from the CSV per request! Tried to format best I can.

**A1**: Date            **B1**: Temp
**A2**: 10/1/1992    **B2**: 53
**A3**: 10/2/1992    **B3**: 58
**A4**: 10/3/1992    **B4**: 62

Comment: Can you include a few lines of your csv file?

Comment: Added CSV lines

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your regex and csv reader are overkill for this. I've made an assumtion about you input format, but the following uses all standard libarary.

Input file example

```
A1: Date B1: Temp
A2: 10/1/1992 B2: 53
A3: 10/2/1992 B3: 58
A4: 10/3/1992 B4: 62
```

Example average calculator per year:

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce

csv_file = '/tmp/temp_example.txt'

with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_fh:
    next(csv_fh)  # skip header
    split_lines = [line.strip('\n').split(' ')[1::2] for line in csv_fh]
    split_lines.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])  # sort by date first
    # group by year
    year_temps = {}
    for key, group in groupby(split_lines, lambda x: x[0].split('/')[-1]):
        year_temps[key] = [int(row[1]) for row in group]
    yearly_averages = {year: (reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, temps) / len(temps))
                       for year, temps in year_temps.items()}
    print(yearly_averages)
```

The strategy here is read in your lines and split them into their columns to start with, then use groupby to create your dict of year: [temps]. The average can be calculated however you most prefer.

Your data is pretty structured to start with and really doesn't need the complexity of regex's to extract the years.